# security risk of opening up a port to access znc

Tags: security, port, irc

I run znc on my home server, and I was thinking about opening up the port for it on the router so I can access znc from my computer at work. My znc accounts are password protected. Is it a substantial security risk to do this, or am I probably safe to go with it? Is there a likelyhood of a person who doesn't have my znc passwords to gain access to the server if I open it for myself?

Comment: No security is completely safe.

Comment: obviously. Whether it was completely safe was not my question.

Comment: Run it chrooted and not as a root user.

Answer (score 2):

By opening the port you are trusting yourself that znc is safe and can't be broken into/compromised from the outside.   I don't think anyone can tell you if its safe or not - that is a call you will need to make yourself.

Depending on how paranoid you are/how important that box is, there are a few (general) things you can do to limit your exposure [ these don't only apply to znc ].

These include:

1. Run znc in a Virtual Machine - if its compromised, only the Virtual Machine is compromised.
2. Firewall to known IP's / ranges - this will limit your ability to get in, but also others ability to get you.
3. If (2) above is not adequate, you might be able to install some kind of port-knocker to make it harder to find and open the znc port.

(Note that all of the above can be done on the computer you are using, none require the support of the router).